# Pandas DataFrame add new column values based on group by multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame as below

```
       Color  Month  Quantity
index                        
0          1      1     34047
1          1      2     36654
2          2      3     37291
3          2      4     35270
4          3      5     35407
5          1     12      9300
```

I want to add a more extra column `PrevoiousMonthQty` to this Dataframe with the filled values in the `Qty` column by the logic that we will group by `(Color, Month)` and the `Month` is the `Previous Month`

The target DataFrame I expected looks like this

[image]

Some logic explanation can be seen as

[image]

Any helps would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using [`Multindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) after finding the previous month:

```
prev_month = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%m').sub(pd.Timedelta(1,unit='m')).dt.month

m = df.set_index(['Color','Month'])['Quantity']

final = (df.assign(Prev_Month_Value=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['Color'],prev_month])
                                                          .map(m).fillna(0)))

#To assign into the existing df,use below code instead of df.assign() which returns a copy
#df['Previous Month Value'] = (pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['Color'],prev_month])
#                                                              .map(m).fillna(0)
```

---

Output:

```
       Color  Month  Quantity  Prev_Month_Value
index                                          
0          1      1     34047            9300.0
1          1      2     36654           34047.0
2          2      3     37291               0.0
3          2      4     35270           37291.0
4          3      5     35407               0.0
5          1     12      9300               0.0
```

Details:

> **Step1** : Find previous month by converting `Month` column to datetime and subtract 1 month using [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html).
>
> **Step2**: Create a multiindex series with Quantity as value and `Color` and `Month` as index.
>
> **Step3**: Create a MultiIndex using `Color` and `prev_month` series and map it back as new column (also fill nan with 0)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) - we'll "merge" on a `prv_month` key which we'll [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) inline:

```
df['PreviousQty'] = (df.assign(prv_month=df['Month'].sub(1).where(lambda x: x!=0, 12))
                     .merge(df,
                            how='left',
                            left_on=['Color', 'prv_month'],
                            right_on=['Color', 'Month'])['Qty_y'].fillna(0))
```

[out]

```
   Color  Month    Qty  PreviousQty
0      1      1  34047       9300.0
1      1      2  36654      34047.0
2      2      3  37291          0.0
3      2      4  35270      37291.0
4      3      5  35407          0.0
5      1     12   9300          0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshape DataFrame and add full months by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot('Color','Month','Oty').reindex(columns=range(1,13))
print (df1)
Month        1        2        3        4        5   6   7   8   9  10  11  \
Color                                                                        
1      34047.0  36654.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   
2          NaN      NaN  37291.0  35270.0      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   
3          NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  35407.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   

Month      12  
Color          
1      9300.0  
2         NaN  
3         NaN
```

Then use [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df1.to_numpy(), 1, axis=1), 
                 index=df1.index, 
                 columns=df1.columns).stack().rename('Previous Month')

df = df.join(s, on=['Color','Month']).fillna({'Previous Month':0})
print (df)
   Index  Color  Month    Oty  Previous Month
0      0      1      1  34047          9300.0
1      1      1      2  36654         34047.0
2      2      2      3  37291             0.0
3      3      2      4  35270         37291.0
4      4      3      5  35407             0.0
5      5      1     12   9300             0.0
```